# Convert a dictionary within a list to rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I currently have a data frame like this:

[image]

and I would like to explode the "listing" column into rows. I would like to use the key in the dictionary as column names, so ideally this is how I would like to data frame to look like this:

```
eventId listingId currentPrice
103337923 1307675567 ...
103337923 1307675567 ...
103337923 1307675567 ...
```

This is what I get with this: print(listing_df.head(3).to_dict())

[image]

Comment: Can you add to question first 3 rows by `print (df.head(3).to_dict())` ?

Comment: @jezrael just added!

Comment: It seems data are not completed :(

Comment: @jezrael it's too long to post, but I uploaded a picture of what the dictionary looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely there should be a better way to do this. But this works. :)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1,2,3,4],
     "b": [5,6,7,8],
     "c": [[{"x": 17, "y": 18, "z": 19}, {"x": 27, "y": 28, "z": 29}],
           [{"x": 37, "y": 38, "z": 39}, {"x": 47, "y": 48, "z": 49}],
           [{"x": 57, "y": 58, "z": 59}, {"x": 27, "y": 68, "z": 69}],
           [{"x": 77, "y": 78, "z": 79}, {"x": 27, "y": 88, "z": 89}]]})
```

[image]

Now you can create a new DataFrame from the above:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df1.columns)
df2_index = 0
for row in df1.iterrows():
    one_row = row[1]
    for list_value in row[1]["c"]:
        one_row["c"] = list_value
        df2.loc[df2_index] = one_row
        df2_index += 1
```

Output is the way you need:

[image]

Now that we have expanded list into separate rows, you can further expand json into columns with:

```
df2[list(df2["c"].head(1).tolist()[0].keys())] = df2["c"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series([x[key] for key in x.keys()]))
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I first have to cover the list i have in the "listing" column to rows, and I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

Comment: @YukinoKondo Updated answer for your use case.

Comment: This was helpful! Thank you.

Comment: @YukinoKondo Please upvote and accept it as an answer if it worked for you. Thanks.